# Swift - Scroll a UIScrollView by tapping button inside a ViewController inside the ScrollView

Tags: ios, swift, uiscrollview

I have a UIScrollView that contains a bunch of view controllers, and in each view controller there is a button that if pressed, should scroll the UIScrollView to a certain position. How do I go about connecting the viewController IBAction for the button to set the scroll position of the UIScrollView?

I know I'll call contentOffset at some point, but I'm struggling with getting the ViewControllers to control the Scroll View.

Comment: In viewContoler,`self.view.superview` is not the scrollVIew?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way you could do it... When you add each `UIViewController.view` to the `UIScrollView` you could also set a `var` in each `UIViewController` that references the `UIScrollView`.

For example, for some `UIViewController`, we'll call it X, put

```
var scrollView: UIScrollView?
```

in it. Then in your class that controls the `UIScrollView`, when you add view X to the `UIScrollView`, also do the following:

```
viewControllerX.scrollView = self.theScrollView
```

Now, when your `IBAction` method is called in `viewControllerX`, you have a reference to the `UIScrollView` and as you said, can do `self.scrollView.contentOffset.y = someValueHere` to change its position.